# How to calculate coordinates $(x,y)$ of rotated polygon?

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

I have coordinates $x,y$ of a point (red point on the image).

[image]

If I rotate the image with a specific angle (for example 30 degrees)
[image]

how can I get the coordinates $x,y$ in the new polygon (which is filled with black)?

Thank you

Comment: You can use the initial coordinates $(x,y)$ to compute the radius $r$ of the circle that the points lie on. Then use polar coordinates $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ to adjust the angle $\theta$ and recover the new coordinates of the point on the rotated image...

Comment: Are the new coordinates centred at the upper left corner, like how computer images are represented? Then after the rotation, the image / the dot is also translated relative to the new origin.

Comment: @Peterwhy yes its a computer processing of an image, the question is how to get the new translated coordinates.

Comment: @JohnMartin Than you I have successfully calculated the new coordinates starting from the origin at the middle of the original image, but I cannot do anything with these as I would need the coordinates from the top-left of the second image instead of the middle of the original image.